# Are you in favour of in-memory filtering or using SQL queries on large number of records in a ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, in-memory

I'm writing a rails finder query that pulls out records for articles sorted by the highest numbers of *approved and public* comments per article.

Which is the best way to run such a query in Ruby on Rails?

As a general rule, are developers in favour of in-memory filtering or running complex SQL queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Letting the database do its job is always best.  Just write the query with a where clause/join/etc. and use a sort by to return only the records you need.  By returning more records and then filtering the data in rails wastes the amount of the data across the "wire" (between DB and app server) and also memory.   Databases are optimized for these sorts of things.  Use an index on the table as necessary.

Another similar post:  http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-talk@googlegroups.com/msg13484.html

Comment: definitely agree... just posted after you... +1

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the results are *so* large, like you're getting a thousand results back, you should LIMIT the results returned, and possibly paginate it depending on your use-case.  But definitely let the DB do it's job, no point int pulling in 10,000 records into ruby memory only to display 25 of them.

Answer (score 3):

The slow part of a web app is almost always the database.

1. running complex queries would cost you a bit in time but the data provided will be meaningful and not that large.
2. Running basic queries will let you have a large dataset you'll have to deal with. This large amount of data could be also long to import.

I'd stick to 1 knowing that you can optimize queries and add indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Almost always, you should use SQL to filter your result-set. The database is much more tuned to performance, and sorting in code can often lead to N+x queries, which can kill performance.

A finder that might do something like what you need might be like this:

```
Article.where('id in (
                SELECT article_id
                FROM comments
                WHERE approved = ? AND public = ?
                ORDER BY count(article_id) DESC
                LIMIT 10 
              )', true, true)
```